# Solr - How to get fuzzy results on price?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

In my data, I have two fields, category and price.  I would like to be able to query on a range, price:[500 TO 1000] and category:Electronics, but still return results under 500 and over 1000, just have them scored lower on relevancy based on the difference from the range.

i.e.  I'd like to show:

product1   $500
product2   $550
product3   $650
product4   $900
product5   $450
product6   $475
product7  $1200

Can someone please shed some light on how this might be accomplished?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: Could you add examples of wrong results and price field definition in your schema?

Comment: Here is the price field: <field name="price" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>   Right now I'm able to query the exact results I want, but I'm not sure how to query the fuzzy results and score them based on relevancy.  For example, I can pull back the 500-1000 results, but I also want the values outside that range, just scored with a lower relevancy.

Comment: you should rather try to boost the range value higher so that they appear before the other range values.

Comment: I think what I need is a function to negatively boost results outside that range.  For example, a range of 500 to 1000 has a median value of 750.  Therefore, a value of 450 is a net distance of 300 from the median, and 1100 is 350 from the median.  I'm just not sure how to apply this to the query.

Comment: This is the formula I eventually used to compute this:  recip(abs(sub(map(price,500,1000,750),750)),1,1000,1000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try using [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29) query parser and [boost query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin) to boost the price range higher than the others.

```
bq=price:[500 TO 1000]^10
```

This would boost all the prices within the range higher than the other to bring them on top.

Comment: I tried that in this query: http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*&deftype=dismax&fl=price,score&bq=price:[500%20TO%201000]^10&numrows=50, but it returned the following results:  475, 395, 420, 493, 480, 525, 490

Comment: are you using edismax query parser ? defType=edismax ?

Comment: I tried both dismax and edismax, and the results were the same.  I'm running solr 3.5.

Comment: I tried on sample data and it worked fine. Can you post your price configuration ? and data sample ?

Comment: price config:  <field name="price" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Comment: sample data:  475.00, 325.00, 525.00, 700.00, 1100.00

Comment: also can you change deftype to defType in your query ? and try again

Comment: Thanks, defType=edismax fixed it!